# Add Pause and Resume functionality while downloading

Tags: go

I am using [this](https://play.golang.org/p/1LAEuOS-09) approach for downloading any file from the given URL. I want to add pause and resume functionality while downloading. I tried to use channels but was not able to succeed.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really "pause" a download. You can only cancel it. You can do that on an `http.Request` by doing `close(req.Cancel)`.

"Resuming" a download is really just making the same request again, but telling the server where to start. Usually by setting a "Range" header.

[This question](https://superuser.com/a/641957/8301) on superuser explains a bit better how it works usually. You will probably need to provide more details if you want us to help you further.